# Mysql inner join with escaped apostrophe result zero

Tags: mysql, join, apostrophe

Myquery :

```
SELECT *
FROM sj t1
INNER JOIN price_list t2 ON replace(replace(t2.product_name,'"',''),"'","") = replace(replace(t1.item,'"',''),"'","")
INNER JOIN convert_list t3 ON replace(replace(t3.product_name,'"',''),"'","") = replace(replace(t1.item,'"',''),"'","")
WHERE t2.id_file = '861'
    AND t1.id BETWEEN 2342 AND 2426
order by t1.id asc
LIMIT 0 , 300
```

The result is zero.

Database :

```
Sample sj item / price_list.product_name / convert_list.product_name : 

zero\'s
one\'s
second\"s
third\'s
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: what happens if you leave out all the replace's and quotes and just join on the existing fields?

Comment: still zero result.. :(

Comment: Can you make a sqlfiddle with sample data?

Comment: idk it's always say something wrong in sql fiddle. but myschma :


CREATE TABLE ForgeRock
 (`id` int, `productName` varchar(20))
;
 
INSERT INTO ForgeRock
 (`id`, `productName`)
VALUES
 (1, "one \\'s "),
 (2, 'two \\"s'),
 (3, "three \\'s")
;
CREATE TABLE table2
 (`id` int, `item` varchar(20))
;
 
INSERT INTO table2
 (`id`, `item`)
VALUES
 (1, "one \\'s "),
 (2, 'two \\"s'),
 (3, "three \\'s")
;

Comment: and my code for sample is : select * from ForgeRock t1
  inner join table2 t2
    on t1.productName=t2.item

Comment: Why do you use these replace statements?

Comment: i'm trying.. cz without replace is can't so i try it.. but with the result replace is still zero..

Comment: for a moment i use replace it with ~0~

Comment: note : sql found ~ as wildcard..